# Jquery tablesorter numbers with hyphens

Tags: javascript, jquery, gridview, jquery-plugins, tablesorter

Jquery tablesorter

I am using Jquery tablesorter and i need to a sort Gridview column which contains number with hyphen tag. The data in the following format and is failing to sort in ASC order **onLoad**: 17-143,17-162,12-144,17-45, 18-12,17-65,18-2. Some values are NULL. Blank value from sql.
This above data should be sort by default as: 12-144,17-45,17-65,17-143,17-162,18-2,18-12

Please assist. Here is the snippet I was trying to use:

```js
<script src="https://github.com/christianbach/tablesorter/blob/master/jquery.tablesorter.js"></script>
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.0.0/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script>
$(document).ready(function() {
    $("#main_gvResource").tablesorter.addParser({ 
        // set a unique id 
        id: 'lblIDSort',
        is: function(s) {
            return false;
        },
        format: function(s) {
            return s.replace('$','').replace(/-/g,'');
        }, 
        type: 'numeric' 
    }); 
    $(function() {
        $("#main_gvResource").tablesorter({
           widgets: ['zebra'],
            headers: {
                1: {//zero-based column index
                    sorter:'gdMobileID'
                }
            }
        });
    });
});
</script>
```

Comment: Did you know you have a document.ready inside your document.ready?

Answer (score 0):

Why all this whitespace? Are you scared, you might see too much of the code at once? ;)

```
$(function() {
    $.tablesorter.addParser({ 
        _regex: /^\d+(?:-\d+)+$/,
        _formatNumber: function(nr){
            //return "0".repeat(5-nr.length) + nr;
            while(nr.length < 5) nr = "0" + nr;
            return nr;
        },

        // set a unique id 
        id: 'gdMobileID',
        is: function(s) {
            //to auto-recognize the column-type
            return this._regex.test(s); 

            //to apply only on columns you defined
            return false;
        }, 

        format: function(s){
            return s.replace(/\d+/g, this._formatNumber);
        }, 
        type: 'text',
    }); 

    $("#main-gvResource").tablesorter({
        widgets: ['zebra'],
        //no need, if you let the parser auto-recognize the columns to apply
        /*headers: {
            1: {//zero-based column index
                sorter:'gdMobileID'
            }
        }*/
    });
});
```

Comment: Tom, Thank you for the snippet. I'm new to Stack overflow and on top of it, new to jQuery also :)
I get error "Object doesn't support property or method 'repeat' "

Comment: Error: Object doesn't support property or method 'repeat'

Comment: OK, that was ES6. fixed it.

Answer (score 0):

My [fork of tablesorter](http://mottie.github.io/tablesorter/docs/) uses a natural sort algorithm by default. You won't need to include any extra code to make it work with that data set ([demo](http://jsfiddle.net/Mottie/bbxxomhx/2/))

```
$(function () {
    $('table').tablesorter({
        theme: 'blue'
    });
});
```